# Libreoffice update can't find JRE

Tags: 20.04, java, libreoffice

I just updated snaps (sudo snap refresh) and now have LibreOffice 24.2. Normally, after an update, LibreOffice Base can't find my Java Runtime Environment. This is usually easily remedied by going into ***Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> Advanced*** and selecting a **JRE** that's listed as installed. This time the box with the installed JREs was blank.

I checked in the terminal:

```
rosalyn@rosalyn-ThinkPad-T14-Gen-1:~$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.22 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu220.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.22+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu220.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So, do I have everything I need and how do I get LibreOffice to work with my database files?

Comment: Libreoffice doesn't need Java for regular use.

Comment: Libreoffice Base needs it. I have no idea why.

Comment: If you use libreoffie as a snap, then the problem is with the snap and you'd need to file a bug report to the developers of the package. You can revert your snap to the previous version of libreoffice with `sudo snap revert libreoffice`.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? In 23.10 LibreOffice is available both as a snap as well as a `deb`. LibreOffice Base is only available for installation from the repositories (the deb version). the snap version does not include the Base component as far as I could see.

Comment: Please don't put the solution inside the question. Consider writing a full answer including the commands used in any by pressing the **Answer Your Own Question** button below. Then accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved and help others.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still learning. Appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got rid of the snap version and installed the deb version from the repositories. Base now finds the JRE. Thanks to all who commented!